# Issues inMinimal Download Strategy SharePoint2019

Tags: sharepoint-server, minimal-download-strategy

We have recently migrated sites from SP2016 to 2019. We have custom masterpage and MDS feature activated. When we click on sitesettings it goes to _layouts/15/start.aspx#/_layouts/15/settings.aspx and never redirect back to settings.aspx page. and hence a blank page renders.

This works fine for newly created sites and problem is only with Migrated sites.

This also works well if we reactivate masterpage feature, but stops working as soon as Application Pool is reset. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

"_layouts/15/start.aspx#" gets attached to the url when MDS feature is activated. Once you deactivate the feature, it will go from the url. Then, try accessing the site settings. MDS Feature is not necessary for SharePoint. It was created just to enhance the performance of SharePoint. It will not impact any functionality which you might be using on SharePoint.

Comment: Yes i understand that this is to enhance the performance that's why we need to make everything work with this feature activated.

Comment: if site settings is hitting, then you can just turn on the feature again. Sometimes it works this way. Try this for a few times.

Comment: Thanks harshal - Already tried multiple times

Comment: Ok. I had faced this issue in 2013 and 2016. Never in Online or 2019.

Answer (score -1):

Per my test, site settings page in 2019 is supported by MDS.

Check the ULS log  to determine the exact cause of the error.

Comment: Would not recommend that! It will disable MDS! Do not enable publishing for existing sites that are not designed as Publishing sites.

Comment: Yes agreed, want to know if Sitesettings page in 2019 is supported by MDS, because this is the only page where this navigation is breaking.

Comment: Ok, i have changed my reply. Per my test, site settings page in 2019 is supported by MDS. For your issue,  test with another user who has full control and compare the results.